# Can I change the starting order number?

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.9

Magento sales order id number Link #100000003.

I'd rather not use order numbers like #100000003, etc., but would like to have staring for #200000003.

How can I change order id numbers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Will this work for you? https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. To do this you will just need phpmyadmin. Please note that following the instruction below is at your own risk. Definitely make a database backup if you are not sure what you are doing.

1. Open your store database. You can do this in phpmyadmin (if you have one) or MySQL Workbench (if you have remote MySQL connections allowed) or in any software that allows you to browse a database.
2. Find table called `eav_entity_type` and open it.
3. In this table find row which has `entity_type_code = order`. Look at value in `entity_type_id` in that row and remember it, it's important. I will assume that order entity ID is 5.
4. Now find table called `eav_entity_store` in your database and open it.
5. If you already have made some orders you should see a row with `entity_type_id = 5`. If not - the table might be empty. If it's empty - I'd recommend you to create an order manually to auto-generate the row. You might also see multiple rows in that table, but you should only focus on `entity_type_id = 5`.
6. When you have the row with `entity_type_id = 5` then you can modify `increment_prefix` and `increment_last_id` values in it. Delete value in `increment_prefix` (this will remove leading 1) and set `increment_last_id` to whatever you want. I'd recommend you to set the new value not lower than part without "10000000", e.g. if it was 100000007 - set it to 7.
7. Now go back to table eav_entity_type, find the same row with entity_type_id = 5 and set increment_pad_length = 1 (this will remove zeros 0000000).
8. Try to place a new order and check what ID it will have.
   Should look like this:

P.S. You can play around with numbers in increment_pad_length (number of 0000000) and increment_prefix (leading digit) to make the order ID look exactly how you want. Just make sure you have a database backup

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='X'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```

Replace the X (in your case 2) with your desired order prefix or remove the quotes and set X to NULL (no quotes)  to disable the order prefix, then run the query.

Comment: I have 2 stores, first store by default increment prefix like 10000, how can I change from 10000 to 30000 for my second store.